# Share vpn tunnel trough ethernet

Tags: linux, openvpn, tunnel

I have a tun1 interface connecting with purevpn trough a small linux server. My tv is also connected to the same router than the linux server. 
I want to know if there is a way to:
1) Configure dg of the tv as the ip of the linux server, and on the linux server, send all the traffic comming from the tv to the tunnel. 
2) Share the tunnel via wifi0 without dnsmasq (I'm also using pihole, then dnsmasq will not work).

EDIT:

```
                 Internet
                    |
192.168.0.3     192.168.0.1    192.168.0.2                     x.x.x.x
SmartTV  --eth--> router <-------eth0------- linux device tun1-Internet->
```

Then what I want is put the DG on the SmartTV as 192.168.0.2, and only the traffic reaching eth0 with IP 192.168.0.3 get redirected to the tun1 interface. 
Also I have pihole working on that server and I want that keep working normally, and why I mentioned dnsmasq, is because pihole is using and I was not able to change so much.

Comment: Dnsmasq is not involved in routing - only IP address assignment (optional, you can use another DHCP server or static addresses) and nameserver (only converting names to IPs - you van just use another server)

Comment: Can you clarify if your router is running openvpn and if so, what router/os it uses?aalso doesndg of TV mean IP of TV? Drawing a network diagram showing devicea, interfaces, netmasks and connections can help us help you.

Comment: Sure, I will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your linux server only for this purpose, or have the resources for a second server, I would recommend doing this with pfSense and OpenVPN.

Way easier to set up.

Comment: How will be the setup? I only have only 1 interface to use.  I use also for pihole and torrent.